# The largest n-bit integer

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

I thought that computing the largest `n`-bit integer would be trivial by using bit-shifts. Specifically, my idea was to set all of the bits to 1, and then shift them to the right:

```
template <typename T = uint16_t>
auto largest(uint8_t n){
    constexpr auto bits = 8*sizeof(T);
    assert(n <= bits);
    return static_cast<T>(-1) >> (bits - n);
}
```

Generally, this idea seems to work. If I print out the result for `0, 1, ...`, I get `0, 1, 3,..., 65535` (as expected).

However, this is where things get strange...

If instead of a `uint16_t`, I use a `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` then I find that

```
largest<uint16_t>(1) = 1
largest<uint32_t>(1) = 1
largest<uint64_t>(1) = 1
```

which is saying, "The largest 1-bit integer is 1" (as expected). However...

```
largest<uint16_t>(0) = 0
largest<uint32_t>(0) = 4294967295
largest<uint64_t>(0) = 18446744073709551615
```

So the value of 0 seems to be an edge case if I use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` to hold the integer type.

To diagnose further, I hard-coded those edge cases so that the compiler can better see it:

```
static_cast<uint16_t>(-1) >> 16;
static_cast<uint32_t>(-1) >> 32;
static_cast<uint64_t>(-1) >> 64;
```

and now for the 32 and 64-bit cases, both GCC and Clang head throw a warning

```
prog.cc:22:31: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   22 |     static_cast<uint64_t>(-1) >> 64;
```

I couldn't find any documentation about why this isn't allowed, and why this only happens for the 32 and 64 bit case. I understand why it might complain about the `count > width`, but the `count == width` case seems valid to me.

Does anybody have some insight as to what is going on?

Also, I would like to hear suggestions for how to compute the largest n-bit integer without having to put in a branch (obviously I could handle the case of `n==0` specially).

Here is a code link so that you don't have to retype everything: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3oqxqQR9ypP5q7yw

Comment: *I couldn't find any documentation about why this isn't allowed* -- [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) and find the **Bitwise shift operators**.  As stated at the link -- *In any case, if the value of the right operand is negative or is greater **or equal to** the number of bits in the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined**.*

Comment: Does “largest 0-bit value” make any sense in your domain? Can you exclude it (and assert if it is used)?

Comment: This limitation that @PaulMcKenzie references on bit shifts (less than number of bits) may see odd but it's due to cpu limitations which would otherwise require emitting extra code to cover these larger shift sizes.

Comment: Why do you use `-1` if you are handling everything with `unsigned`s?  Have you read about the `~` operator  (to get all ones, you can just use `~0U`, which will not be undefined, or implementation defined behaviour, as `-1` in one's complement implementation is not all ones, but just the bit0 and the sign bit)

Comment: Honestly, I probably should be using numeric_limits here. -1 is just the first thing that popped in my mind. You have a valid point

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup table to avoid branching.